# Differential Equation Word Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm new to this site. I'm taking a differential equations course this summer and this question is from my first homework assignment. I was able to do all of my homework questions that just required me to solve the equations, but I have a hard time setting up equations from a word problem. I went to my TA's office hours this afternoon and he wasn't sure how to solve the problem, but recommended I try posting it on this site. 
Here is the problem:

Consider a system of two tanks which hold salt-water. Fresh water flows into Tank 1. The well-mixed contents of Tank 1 flow into Tank 2. The well- mixed contents of Tank 2 flow out of the system. All three flow rates are 5 gal/min. Tank 1 initially holds 100gal of salt-water, Tank 2 initially holds 200gal, and each tank begins with 50lbs of salt.

(a) Find x(t), the amount of salt (in lbs) in Tank 1 at time t.

(b) Find the y(t), the amount of salt (in lbs) in Tank 2 at time t.

(c)Find the maximum amount of salt ever in Tank 2.

Thanks in advance! Also, I'm not necessarily looking for a solution; any tips you have towards an approach to the problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the first tank. How many salt flows out per minute? Since you have $x$ lbs of salt into $100$ gal and every minute 5 gal flow out, you should have:
$$
 x' = - \frac{5}{100}x.
$$
Analogously:
$$
y' = \frac{5}{100} x - \frac{5}{200} y.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! When I go to solve the second equation though, I'm solving dy/dt=(5x(t)/100)- (5y(t)/200). I can't figure out how to solve it, it's some kind of substitution, right?

Comment: Solve the first equation, put the result in the second and solve.